# How can we write blank file in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile()

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can we write a blank file in C# Response Object?

I want to write a file whose path does not exist at all.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile("blank.txt")
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Why would you want to do it? If a file is not existing you should throw a HttpException(404)

Comment: I am working with downloader. If file not exits then need to display a default file like errorLog.txt –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not. What you can do is, make an empty file and name it "blank.txt" and keep it in your solution.

Could I know the reason for writing blank file. It is not equivalent of not writing anything in response ?

**UPDATE**

Building on Jon's idea, you can even simply write the HTTP headers

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename= errorLog.txt");
Response.AddHeader("content-length","0");
Response.Flush();


Response.End();
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you already have a errorLog.txt file, use Response.WriteFile directly

Comment: I am working with downloader. If file not exits then need to display a default file like errorLog.txt

Comment: Response.AddHeader("content-length",0); is encountering syntax error, The best overloaded method match for  Response.AddHeader("content-length",0) has some invalid Arguments..

Comment: Above code has not content in errorLog.txt file. so that it is encountering **Corrupted Content Error**

Actually i have need to create a file by using System.IO.File.Create() method

Comment: what if you could just write a blank space ?

Comment: Right now i am using this code..

string _str = Path.Combine(root, "errorLog.txt");
FileStream fs = File.Create(_str);
Byte[] info = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Error: Requested file is not exist on server.");
fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
fs.Close();   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(_str);

Comment: Sir, Your first line of answer is more helpful. I have done that.

Comment: If you have errorLog.txt file on server, then do not use this code. Instead use directly Response.WriteFile method. The above code was an attempt to write just HTTP headers and send it to client. It would then not require any text file

Comment: I have not  errorLog.txt file. So that i am creating. Actually my application is encountering error  like **"File Corrupted"**. So that i am creating file manually.

Answer (score 2):

Look at what headers are sent for a *non-empty* file, and then simple write out the same headers yourself (changing the content length, of course) but with no data.

(I'm assuming that `WriteFile` *does* fill in some headers around the file name etc. If it doesn't, it's even simpler :)

Comment: Excellent idea. I have updated my answer to reflect your view. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=blank.txt");
        Response.End();
```